# Jquery mobile autocomplete with php

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I'm trying to get the Jquery mobile autocomplete demo on the jquery mobile website (http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html) work with a php file, if i tested in firebug, I have the callback response working in this format: [{"label":"278","value":"ANGELIC HOLISTIC HEALING"}]
But I don't know why is not showing any results on my html, here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#searchPage", function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "services/search2.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                term: $input.val()
            },

        })
        .then( function ( response ) {

            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val.value + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});
```

});

the php:

```
(database connection)
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

$return = array();
$query = mysql_query("select * from directory2 where business like '%$q%'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
  {
      array_push($return, array(
        'label'      => $row['ID'], 
        'value'    => html_entity_decode($row['business'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') )
    );
  }     

echo(json_encode($return));
```

the html

```
<div data-role="content">
<h3>Cities worldwide</h3>
```

After you enter **at least three characters** the autocomplete function will show all possible matches.

```
<<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a business..." data-filter-theme="d"></ul>

</div>
```

Please any help will be soo much appreciated, I've been searching for this a lot everywhere and no luck!

Comment: have you checked that your ajax is returning correctly? put `console.log(response);` into your callback

Comment: I tried to check some info about checking ajax, but I really don't have much experience, but if you could check what I'm seeing in my firebug please? here's the screenshot: http://synergyholisticdirectory.com/ajax.jpg